# UIView Masking not working correctly with autolayout

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I'm trying to mask the bottom and top corner of a UITableView. I've found that the following code works for a specific screen size (iPhone 6) and produces these results:

[image]

It's achieved by applying the following code:

```
class func maskRowForIndexPath<T>(cell : T ,indexPath: NSIndexPath, count : Int) -> T{
        let const = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width * (6 / (cell as! UIView).frame.size.width)
        let cornerRadii = CGSizeMake(const, const)
        let row = indexPath.row
        if row == 0 {
            let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: (cell as! UITableViewCell).bounds, byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner.TopLeft.union(.TopRight), cornerRadii: cornerRadii).CGPath
            (cell as! UITableViewCell).layer.mask = maskLayer
        }

        if row == count-1{
            let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: (cell as! UITableViewCell).bounds, byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner.BottomLeft.union(.BottomRight), cornerRadii: cornerRadii).CGPath
            (cell as! UITableViewCell).layer.mask = maskLayer
        }
        return cell
    }
```

As you can see, I added a snippet to try and make the corner radii proportional to the screen size (and essentially the view size) in this line:

```
    let const = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width * (6 / (cell as! UIView).frame.size.width)
```

The `maskRowForIndexPath` method is calling inside my UITableView `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let row = indexPath.row
        let info = (indexPath.section == 0) ? firstSectionTitles : secondSectionTitles
        let cell : AccountHomeTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AccountHomeTableViewCell") as! AccountHomeTableViewCell
        cell.titleLabel.attributedText = attributedTitleForCellString(info[row].title)
        cell.cellImageView.image = UIImage(named: info[row].imageName)
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        UIView.maskRowForIndexPath(cell, indexPath: indexPath, count: info.count)

        return cell
    }
```

When I run the app on an iPhone 6+ (and smaller iPhone 5) screen, the view is masked improperly:

[image]

Any idea on how to solve?

Thanks :)

Comment: How about applying the mask to the UITableView? Or are these sections? Also, what is the size of your storyboard (Any-Any or anything else)?

Comment: Applying the mask to the tableview won't get the appropriate result - for example in cases where there are multiple sections (as in the image provided). This is one tableview, so if I round the tableview's corners, the first sections bottom corners wont be rounded as well as the second sections top corners. I'm not using size classes, since its strictly an iPhone app. The storyboard inferred size of the view controllers is 4.7 inches (iPhone 6). @vrwim

Comment: Have you tried applying the mask in tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) instead of in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Answer (score 0):

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you are using your custom cell, and to give corner radii in your method:

```
class func maskRowForIndexPath<T>(cell : T ,indexPath: NSIndexPath, count : Int) -> T
```

...you are using `UITableViewCell`. Try changing to your `customCell` class.

Comment: Don't see how this would matter, since my custom cell is a subclass of `UITableViewCell` - the parameter class is just so it will work for all `UITableViewCell`s

Comment: Though your customcell is a subclass of UITableviewCell but you have to mention your customcell and not your UITableViewCell , as the UITableView by default will manage only UITableViewCell and not yours customCell. So in your method change to your customCell . this will solve your issue